# Find the APK names for /system/app

Tags: android, adb

How to find the apk names for /system/app?
because some of the apk names are not in "pm list packages -f"
they are all system apps and I just need to know the APK names like an example below for "com.android.systemui" is "SystemUI.apk"

```
adb shell ps |grep u0_
u0_a98    2612  1936  542612 39060 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.systemui
u0_a29    2712  1936  528736 32312 ffffffff 00000000 S android.process.media
u0_a19    2728  1936  574888 39160 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.process.location
u0_a1     2774  1936  672892 69800 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.app.launcher
u0_a19    2816  1936  561372 34300 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.process.gapps
u0_a10    2920  1936  508492 27280 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.provider.logsprovider
u0_a10    2951  1936  540656 31176 ffffffff 00000000 S android.process.acore
u0_a83    2968  1936  523328 33532 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.app.FlashBarService
u0_a19    2989  1936  679548 38880 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.gms
u0_a1     3135  1936  509724 26732 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.hero.accuweather.widget:remote
u0_a416   3227  1936  514676 26728 ffffffff 00000000 S android.process.acore
u0_a153   3237  1936  508796 25076 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.msc.nts.android.proxy
u0_a23    3250  1936  509088 29088 ffffffff 00000000 S com.samsung.android.providers.context
u0_a154   3263  1936  522064 26792 ffffffff 00000000 S com.tgrape.android.radar
u0_a116   3283  1936  508352 25828 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.sCloudRelayData
u0_a10    3827  1936  547276 26544 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.contacts
u0_a131   3890  1936  508284 27592 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.widgetapp.alarmclock
u0_a81    3940  1936  512444 25816 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.phone
u0_a0     3969  1936  509544 28652 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.daemonapp.ap.accuweather
u0_a63    4171  1936  510740 25308 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.esdk.elm
u0_a150   4590  1936  508320 26556 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.pagebuddynotisvc
u0_a152   4615  1936  521180 30564 ffffffff 00000000 S com.vlingo.midas
u0_a71    4834  1936  511536 28676 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.spp.push
u0_a61    4890  1936  508464 29040 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.app.keyguard
u0_a21    4936  1936  514832 30640 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.app.clockpackage
u0_a142   4985  1936  523532 33228 ffffffff 00000000 S com.navigon.navigator_select_samsung_pac
u0_a133   5120  1936  530444 33024 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.music:main
u0_a76    5253  1936  514732 31360 ffffffff 00000000 S com.osp.app.signin
u0_a67    5304  1936  537988 32792 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.apps.plus
u0_a49    5370  1936  510360 26860 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.app.controlpanel
u0_a1     5383  1936  516100 28040 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.widgetapp.SPlannerAppWidget
u0_a123   5398  1936  513900 29920 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.providers.calendar
u0_a110   5417  1936  508664 28288 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.daemonapp.ap.yahoostock.stockclock
u0_a114   5437  1936  509020 28520 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.sCloudSync
u0_a7     5452  1936  514584 27292 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.app.music:service
u0_a80    5471  1936  531516 32000 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.gallery3d
u0_a87    5494  1936  520808 36556 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.mms
u0_a108   5526  1936  508572 28048 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.daemonapp.ap.yahoonews
u0_a79    5547  1936  516536 29376 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.calendar
u0_a71    5575  1936  511464 27688 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.spp.push:RemoteDlcProcess
u0_a71    5600  1936  510424 27620 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.spp.push:RemoteNotiProcess
u0_a19    5612  1936  541816 31700 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.gms:snet
u0_a36    5626  1936  530432 32932 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.gm
u0_a19    5646  1936  512412 28192 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.gsf.login
u0_a13    5698  1936  508260 27816 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.provider.badge
u0_a19    5735  1936  543580 31000 ffffffff 00000000 S com.google.android.gms.wearable
u0_a65    5819  1936  545916 43508 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.vending
u0_a161   5869  1936  560048 45552 ffffffff 00000000 S com.example.timeouttest
u0_a74    6225  1936  514440 28872 ffffffff 00000000 S com.sec.android.app.samsungapps.una2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `pm` command itself.
`pm help`

```
pm list packages: prints all packages
Options:
    -f: see their associated file.
```

Since you are trying to map the APK file name to thier associated packages.
The command `pm list packages -f` will do just that.

For filtering only the `/system/app`. Use `grep`.

Like this:

```
$ pm list packages -f | grep /system/app                                                                                     
package:/system/app/TimeService.apk=com.qualcomm.timeservice
package:/system/app/Calculator.apk=com.android.calculator2
package:/system/app/HTMLViewer.apk=com.android.htmlviewer
package:/system/app/Bluetooth.apk=com.android.bluetooth
package:/system/app/Calendar.apk=com.android.calendar
package:/system/app/Browser.apk=com.android.browser
package:/system/app/Camera2.apk=com.android.camera2
```

Comment: right, I used the same command but for some packages like "u0_a416   3227  1936  514676 26728 ffffffff 00000000 S android.process.acore" cant find them under pm list packages -f

Comment: Could you please use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and give me the output for `adb shell ps` and `adb shell ps | grep u0`.